# Problem running vscode from terminal

Tags: command-line

I followed the [instructions](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/setup) for installing vscode:

> Linux
>
> 1. Download Visual Studio Code for Linux.
> 2. Make a new folder and extract VSCode-linux-x64.zip inside that folder.
> 3. Double click on Code to run Visual Studio Code.
>
> Tip: If you want to run VS Code from the terminal, create the following link substituting /path/to/vscode/Code with the absolute> path to the Code executable
>
> `sudo ln -s /path/to/vscode/Code /usr/local/bin/code`
>
> Now, you can simply type `code .` in any folder to start editing files
>   in that folder.

However upon typing `code .` I get:

```
No command 'code' found, did you mean:   
Command 'cone' from package 'cone' (universe)   
Command 'tcode' from package 'emboss' (universe)   
Command 'ode' from package 'plotutils' (universe)   
Command 'cdde' from package 'cdde' (universe)   
Command 'node' from package 'node' (universe)    
Command 'node' from package 'nodejs-legacy' (universe)   
Command 'cde' from package 'cde' (universe)   
Command 'cobe' from package 'python-cobe' (universe)
```

What have I done wrong?

Clicking on the Code executable works ok.

```
nikolai@dante:~$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/code    
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 12 Oct  3 17:13 /usr/local/bin/code -> /vscode/Code    
nikolai@dante:~$ echo $PATH    
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

Comment: Please append the outputs of `ls -l /usr/local/bin/code` and `echo $PATH`

Comment: @nephente done.

Comment: Did you really unpack VSCode to `/vscode/` ? Please check the path. I would also advise to put it into `/opt/vscode`. That's what `/opt` is for.

Answer (score 3):

I used to have the same problem, I just removed the created link with:

```
unlink /usr/local/bin/code/Code
```

Then re created the link directly under "/usr/local/bin" like below

```
sudo ln -s /path/to/vscode/Code /usr/local/bin
```

Works for me, let us know if it worked ...

Answer (score 2):

I installed code-insiders through ubuntu softwares. since it is a snap install so it was installed into /snap/bin/code-insiders . to check whether an application is installed. run

```
$ dpkg -l
```

it gives complete list of applications which are installed in the system. look for `code-insiders` there. to check the installation directory of code-insiders, run

```
$ which code-insiders
```

In my case it was showing `/snap/bin/code-insiders`

then i linked it to `/usr/bin` by running the command.

```
$ sudo ln -s /snap/bin/code-insiders /usr/bin
```

and then all done. then i could run code from terminal by using

```
$ code-insiders .
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the path `/vscode/Code` corret or did you mean `~/vscode/Code`? Check the link you created...

Or if you prefer you can install VSCode with [this script](https://gist.github.com/brunolm/65a760f6130fd2e1d39c)

```
curl -L https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=620884 > /tmp/vscode.zip
unzip -qq /tmp/vscode.zip -d /tmp
sudo cp -r /tmp/VSCode-linux-x64 /opt/vscode
sudo ln -s /opt/vscode/Code /usr/local/bin/vscode
sudo rm -rf /tmp/VSCode-linux-x64
sudo rm -f /tmp/vscode.zip
sudo touch /usr/share/applications/vscode.desktop
sudo chmod 777 /usr/share/applications/vscode.desktop
sudo echo -e "[Desktop Entry]\nName=VSCode\nComment=Visual Studio Code\nExec=/opt/vscode/Code\nIcon=/opt/vscode/resources/app/vso.png\nType=Application\nVersion=1.0\nTerminal=false\nCategories=Development" > /usr/share/applications/vscode.desktop
sudo chmod 644 /usr/share/applications/vscode.desktop
```

I created it as `vscode` rather than just `code`. But if you want `code` just change this line:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/vscode/Code /usr/local/bin/vscode
```

to

```
sudo ln -s /opt/vscode/Code /usr/local/bin/code
```

And it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and the solution was to use absolute path for `/path/to/vscode/Code`. For example, I extracted the compressed file in my `home` directory and renamed it to `VSCode` and run following command to make the symlink.

`$ sudo ln -s /home/lekhnath/VSCode/code /usr/local/bin`

where **lekhnath** is my username.

And it worked!!

Answer (score 0):

I used to have the same problem and I solved it installing vscode again using

> sudo apt install code

Now it works

Comment: `E: Unable to locate package code`. Doesn't work on Zorin 16.1. EDIT: works after this: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-visual-studio-code-on-ubuntu-20-04/#installing-visual-studio-code-with-apt

Answer (score 0):

Typing `wsl --shutdown` and then running `code .` in the newly opened Linux Distro should make it work for you if other answers didn't help.